# How to perform GET using hbase rest with hashed rowkey

Tags: rest, hbase

I have the following row key: `\xFE\xA1\x52\x272014-02-14T00:00:00Z`
I am trying to use hbase rest to perform a `GET`.

Performing the following, I get `404 Not Found`:

```
curl -v -X GET http://{server name}:8080/{table}/\xFE\xA1\x52\x272014-02-14T00:00:00Z
```

I have also tried url encoding the "\" and ":" for the row key but no luck.

Any ideas?